# How to get ALL logs from Chrome console using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, logging, protractor

I want to get all logs from Chrome console using Protractor. I set up next preferences in my Protractor config file:

```
capabilities: {
    loggingPrefs: {
        'browser': 'ALL'
    }
}
```

But I get only INFO level logs. And next command returns 'INFO' instead of 'ALL':

```
browser.driver.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (entries) {
    var pLogs = entries.filter(function (entry) {
        console.log("entry level name = ", entry.level.name);
    });
});
```

How can I get **ALL** log entries? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue with a workaround inside at Protractor github issue tracker:

- [loggingPrefs not respected - always INFO logging](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2436)

Comment: Thank you. I spent 2 days on this issue.